# Group folders inside another folder

Tags: php

I have image contents that are stored inside folders like this:

```
Contents
--> Content1
--> Content2543
--> Content3654
--> Content4456
--> Content5456
--> Content6765
--> Content9565
```

And so on until content 700k.

I need to change the way contents are stored so that there arent more than 1000 folders on the same folder, so i decided to move the Contents inside another folder within a range, for instance, Contents with id between 1 and 1000 goes inside a folder names Contents1-1000

The expected result would be:

```
Contents
--> Contents1-1000
    --> Content1
--> Contents1001-2000
--> Contents2001-3000
    --> Content2543
--> Contents3001-4000
    --> Content3654
--> Contents4001-5000
    --> Content4456
--> Contents5001-6000
    --> Content5456
--> Contents6001-7000
    --> Content6765
--> Contents7001-8000
--> Contents8001-9000
--> Contents9001-10000
    --> Content9565
```

I know how to direct new contents into this folder structure, but i dont know how to addapt current contents to this structure, so far i have this:

```
$directories = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/contents/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);

foreach($directories as $dir) {
 rename(basename($dir), basename($dir));
}
```

But im missing how to iterate over the folders name so that content 26304 goes inside the folder 26001-27000.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
$directoryIterator = new DirectoryIterator($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/contents');

foreach ($directoryIterator as $fileInfo) {
    if ($fileInfo->isDot() || !$fileInfo->isDir()) {
        continue;
    }

    preg_match('/\d+$/', $fileInfo->getFilename(), $directoryNumber);

    $rangeMin = floor($directoryNumber[0] / 1000) * 1000 + 1;
    $range = array($rangeMin, $rangeMin + 999);

    $newPath = $fileInfo->getPath()
        . '/Contents'
        . implode('-', $range)
        . '/'
        . $fileInfo->getFilename();

    rename($fileInfo->getPathname(), $newPath);
}
```

PS: Please note that this code is not tested and may need some enhancements to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
$directories = glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/acuarelas/contenidos/*' , GLOB_ONLYDIR);



foreach($directories as $dir) {
$id = basename($dir);

$alocator = floor($id/1000);
$alocatordir = ($alocator*1000)."-".(($alocator*1000)+1000);


echo $alocatordir."/".$id."<br>";

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you could do it for any individual contents file `$curFilename`:

```
$curFilename = "Content26304";

preg_match('/[0-9]/', $curFilename, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

$id = substr($curFilename, $matches[0][1]);
$minFolder = (floor($id / 1000) * 1000) + 1;
$maxFolder = ($minFolder - 1) + 1000;
```

So you can see the output:

```
echo "File [$curFilename] should go to [$minFolder]-[$maxFolder]";
```